# Padding messes up flexbox alignment

Tags: sass, flexbox

I am trying to have two items as links in the top right corner of the page. 
I posted my code on [codepen](https://codepen.io/charlesscheuer/pen/OoJEGb) for a visual example. Whenever I add padding for the visit button the about goes up on the page.

CSS:

```
   .navigation {
     display: flex;
     justify-content: space-between;
     align-content: center;
     &-list {
     display: flex;
     align-self: center;
     list-style: none;
     font-size: 2rem;
    }
   &-item {



        &-visit {
       background-color: $color-tertiary;
       padding: 2rem;
         }
     }
  }
```

Html:

```
       <div class="container">
       <navigation class="navigation">
        <h1 class="porto">Porto</h1>
        <ul class="navigation-list">
         <li class="navigation-item">About</li>
          <li class="navigation-item navigation-item-visit">Visit</li>
       </ul>
      </navigation>

   </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try removing the `height` in `&-item` and `padding-bottom` in `&-visit`.